# Update query (access & vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

**QUESTION 1**

I have to update some fields of a table of access according to the value of parameter. If this paramter is "true" I need to update.

> **Table**
>
> idInvoice
>
> price
>
> percentageTax1
>
> tax1
>
> percentageTax2
>
> tax2
>
> total
>
> **Example values:**
>
> idinvoice: 12300
>
> price: 100 €
>
> percentageTax1: 10 %
>
> tax1= 10€
>
> percentageTax2: 5 %
>
> tax2: 5€
>
> total: 115 € (result: 100€+10€+5€)

Ok. If the parameter on that I have commented before is "true" I must update the percentages and then update the total. I need to replace the "old" percentages by new percent.

Ok I can do it in 3 queries:

```
update invocies set percentageTax1=20,tax1=price *(percentageTax1/100) where idInvoice=@number and percentageTax1=10

update invocies set percentageTax2=7,tax2=price *(percentageTax2/100) where idInvoice=@number and percentageTax2=5

update invocies set total=price+tax1+tax2 where idInvoice=@number
```

**. But my question is:**

is there any an alternative to do this  in 1 query?

### QUESTION 2

Other question about update.

If I have 2 linked tables

EXAMPLE TABLE INVOICE

idInvoice

total

EXAMPLE TABLE DETAIL

idInovice

Line

price

The "total" field is the total sum of the field "price" of the table "detail"

how it would be the "query" to update "total" field?

TOTAL field need to be stored in database

---

### SOLUTION QUESTION 2:

is possible if I do this query. Example.

update table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id set table1.field1=table2.fieldX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the calculated fields if possible.

```
update invocies 
set percentageTax1 = IIf(percentageTax1=10, 20, percentagetax1)
 , percentageTax2 = IIf(percentageTax2=5, 7, percentageTax2)
where idInvoice=@number AND (percentageTax1=10 OR percentageTax2=5)
```

Comment: my question is about Access. Iif not runs in access.

Comment: what do you mean?  iif IS an Access function, in almost every other RDBMS it's a CASE statement

Comment: Access vs. Jet/ACE has differences in what functions can be executed. He's not using Access, only Jet/ACE.

Comment: sorry. yes it runs

The solution of question 2, I've posted in my 1st message

Answer (score 2):

It is more common to pull out the invoice you want to work on, do the maths in the code to update the values, then put all the updated values back in the database in one go.

There are a thousand different ways of doing this!

possibly one place to start is http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/eisk

or here 
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/an-overview-of-inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-vb

Comment: where is the example? Only I need to know is possible to execute all in 1 query.I am not using dataset neither adapters.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to Question two.
Unless there is some special need to store the calculated result in the database I would just calculate it each time I wanted to do anything with the total.

This may not scale if you are writing StackOverflow, but for normal use it saves a place where data can slip out of sync.

Comment: Yes I need to store "Total" field in database. Is important (a law) Only I have put a basic example. My case is more complex. The example is not real. It is only in order that understand the question.